# Where can i find the path/URL of a module after installing it?

Tags: routes, 9

I just installed two modules on a Drupal 9 site: https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_forum and https://www.drupal.org/project/answers.

I want to get the URL where all posts/questions are listed and use it in a menu, but I cannot find where those are. The only thing I found is the URL for creating new posts and questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the routing file for modules to determine the paths the module declares. In your case you will look at `simple_forum.routing.yml` and `project_answers.routing.yml`. Look at the `path` key for the various entries.

Comment: it is quite interesting, the first path returns an empty array, and the second one return a list of ratings, there is no path that returns something like a list of topics, i mean a list like the main page list of stack overflow. Maybe... do i have to code something?. this is the route file of simple forum: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/simple_forum/-/blob/8.x-1.2/simple_forum.routing.yml

Comment: The README may give more details https://git.drupalcode.org/project/simple_forum/-/blob/8.x-1.2/README.txt

Comment: Yea i already read that, it doesnt say anything about a list of topics, it only describes how to create a new topic. also the answers module doesnt say anything about that. but there are screenshots with this list of topics: https://www.drupal.org/project/answers

Comment: You may need to create your own list with the Views module that ships with core.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking for the routes individually module by module, you can install the [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) temporarily in your local environment (never use on a production server) and go to `/devel/routes` to get a list of all routes currently active for the site.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the URL where all posts/questions are listed and use it
> in a menu

To answer your question, for those 2 specific modules, there simply isn't one. Those 2 modules do not provide any.

You can always use Views to create a page view and add title and comment count as fields and format its display as a table.